# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rasax'

Tags: rasa, rasa-core, rasa-x

The installation of `rasa x` is successful but yet it says that `rasax` module could not be found.

Python version : 3.6.5

pip version: 21.1.2

rasa version: 1.9.5

```
amit.pathak@AmitPathak-L MINGW64 /d/ (master)
$ "C:\Python365\python.exe" -m pip install rasa-x --extra-index-url https://pypi.rasa.com/simple
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.rasa.com/simple
Requirement already satisfied: rasa-x in c:\python365\lib\site-packages (0.0.1)
(venv) 
amit.pathak@AmitPathak-L MINGW64 /d/ (master)
$ "C:\Python365\python.exe" -m rasa x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python365\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Python365\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python365\lib\site-packages\rasa\__main__.py", line 102, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python365\lib\site-packages\rasa\__main__.py", line 91, in main     
    cmdline_arguments.func(cmdline_arguments)
  File "C:\Python365\lib\site-packages\rasa\cli\x.py", line 326, in rasa_x     
    run_locally(args)
  File "C:\Python365\lib\site-packages\rasa\cli\x.py", line 414, in run_locally
    from rasax.community import local  # pytype: disable=import-error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rasax'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with rasa-x.
try this:

pip               :         21.1.2
Rasa Version      :         2.7.0
Minimum Compatible Version: 2.6.0
Rasa SDK Version  :         2.7.0
Rasa X Version    :         0.40.1
Python Version    :         3.8.9

> pip install -U pip & rasa-x --extra-index-url https://pypi.rasa.com/simple --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver